# Cree un pipe para buscar en base al id pero pese a que coinciden da error

Tags: typescript

Estoy practicando el tema de los pipes y no logro entender por que cuando intento buscar por id termina rompiendo completamente.

Me devuelve correctamente el filter, me devuelve correctamente el "persona" (Es decir, si tiro un console log de ambos me tiran todos los id de persona y el id seleccionado), pero al momento de tirar un filter en base al id de persona y al filter el cual me devuelve un value la cual es un number **"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"**

```
return items.filter(({ persona }) => persona.id === filter);
```

El array de persona esta creado de la siguiente forma

```
  persona = [
    { Nombre: "Juan Topo", id: 1, },
    { Nombre: "Pedro", id: 2, },
    { Nombre: "Marcelo", id: 3, },
  ];
```

Verifique si el pipe estaba mal creado pero no, cuando hago un filtro de texto funciona correctamente, pero yo necesito filtrar por id.
Es mas, si le digo que en base a un null filtre todos los datos de persona me los filtra todos.
El filtro en base al null es :

```
  if (!filter) {
    return items;
}
```

Select para filtrar

```
  <ion-select
              interface="action-sheet"
              placeholder="Seleccione el id ."
              [(ngModel)]="opcion" id="opcion">
              <ion-select-option value="0">
                Todos
              </ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="1">
                1
              </ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="2">
                2
              </ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="3">
                 3
              </ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al usar `({ persona })`, se está indicando que se quiere usar la propiedad `persona` que se encuentra en el objeto que recibe como argumento. Y el objeto no contiene esa propiedad por eso el `undefined`.

Hay dos opciones de solución:

1. Cambiar `persona` por `id` que sí es una propiedad existente `items.filter(({ id }) =>id === filter)`
2. No usar "destructuring" y recibir el objeto completo `items.filter( persona  => persona.id === filter);`